# MultiSelect Menu in Action Bar Sherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, multi-select

I wan to have one action bar with one "menu" button. (Until here I know how to do) But Now I want to do that, when the users Clicks on any subitem of the menu, don't close this menu.

Said in other words, I want to enable the multiselect menu in action bar sherlock, but I dont know how to do it.

Can someone explain me some way to achive it?

Thats what I have

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity{
    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.Sherlock___Theme_Light);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Testing");
        actionBar.setSubtitle("test");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

And this is the XML Menu file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        android:title="Menu"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/subitem1"
                android:title="SubMenu1"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/subitem2"
                android:title="SubMenu2"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/subitem3"
                android:title="SubMenu3"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/subitem4"
                android:title="SubMenu4"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```